# Como excluir vários elemento de uma list() de uma só vez no R?

Tags: r, lista

Eu tenho a seguinte lista:

`x <- list("1", 1, 2, 2.1, TRUE, "yes", "necessary", 31, FALSE, "FALSE")`

gostaria de excluir dela todos os elementos que **NÃO** são números inteiros e nem caracteres, no caso os elementos que estão na posição [4], [5] e [9]
já tentei fazer:

`x <- x[-4][-5][-9]`

porém apenas o primeiro elemento é retirado corretamente, de modo que o índice de cada elemento posterior é alterado com a retirado do primeiro, a lista fica:

```
[[1]]
[1] "1"

[[2]]
[1] 1

[[3]]
[1] 2

[[4]]
[1] TRUE

[[5]]
[1] "necessary"

[[6]]
[1] 31

[[7]]
[1] FALSE

[[8]]
[1] "FALSE"
```

como retirar os elementos da posição [4], [5] e [9] sem que haja mudança do índice dos elementos indesejados?

Comment: Tente assim `x2 = x[c(-4,-5,-9)]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para retirar *exatamente* as posições 4, 5 e 9, basta informar um vetor com essas posições para a lista:

```r
x <- list("1", 1, 2, 2.1, TRUE, "yes", "necessary", 31, FALSE, "FALSE")

x[-c(4, 5, 9)]
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "1"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "yes"
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] "necessary"
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] 31
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> [1] "FALSE"
```

Mas se quiser algo mais geral, que sirva para qualquer situação em que deseja excluir de uma lista todos os elementos que não são números inteiros e nem caracteres, use a solução abaixo.

A função `testar.inteiro` verifica se cada elemento da lista está definido apenas como um número sem parte decimal.

```r
testar.inteiro <- function(x){
  !grepl("[^[:digit:]]", format(x, digits = options()$digits, scientific = FALSE))
}

x[!(!sapply(x, is.character) & !sapply(x, testar.inteiro))]
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "1"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "yes"
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] "necessary"
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] 31
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> [1] "FALSE"
```

Note que, no exemplo original, o primeiro elemento da lista é `"1"`, que para o R não é um número inteiro. Isso é um caractere. Entretanto, a função `testar.inteiro` mantém esse elemento na lista, pois a pergunta pedia por isso em seu resultado esperado,.